# VMWARE Hosts - Seperate from rest of the network ip sec?

Tags: windows, active-directory, vmware-esx, ipsec

I have a situation with the following setup:

ESX Host - ESX1
Vmware guest os : box1,box2,box3,box4.

There is a special VPN connected to box1 and box3.

All of the guest OS's have full access to the rest of the network.

My aim is to have two groups:

box1 and box3 in one group
box2 and box4 in another group.

These should only have access to their own group, and the vpn that comes into box1/2. They should not be able to see the rest of the network.

Due to some port and vm issues, is there a way I can do this from the guest OS's? using internal firewall or ipsec etc?

The aim is to have a duplicate AD environment from our real network, setup on the box3 and box4. Needs to be a duplicate and co-exist as this is dev for some interfaces from other systems, that I cannot pipe of to a dev environment.

A bit of a strange request, but I am hoping someone can poke me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of ESX?

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you would do this physically - you have a separate physical network with your test servers on, with its own DC on that network.  If you needed any kind of communication with your live system, you'd use a firewall/router connected to both networks to control exactly what packets are allowed to pass between the networks.

You can do this in VMware ESX by creating a new vSwitch for your dev environment.  You could create a dedicated firewall VM running something like [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/), and connect that to both the dev vSwitch and your production vSwitch.

You want to be *very* careful about letting the DC on the dev system in particular talk to the production network!  Set up your firewall rules before connecting the firewall/router to the production network.